# Change Title and/or Snippet of Marker dynamically?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

- How to change the Title and/or Snippet property of an Marker dynamically ?

Comment: Please. Could You explain Yourself why downvote and vote close ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are methods to do that in the API v2:

```
marker.setTitle(String title);
marker.setSnippet(String snippet);
```